# A bit of help understanding javascript splits

Tags: javascript

I'm basically trying to debug some javascript and i dont really understand it.

this is the code

`if(a&&0<=a.indexOf("://")&&a.split("/")[2]!=f.location.href.split("/")[2])`

here are the values

a=`"/cc/subs/TOS-turkish.srt"`

f.location - `"http://192.168.55.108:5555/cc/mypage.html"`

This might be a case of how the heck every are they suppose to match.  I just really am confused now.

Thanks.

Comment: When you split f.location on "/", it's going to split on each of the slashes in "//:", so your index is wrong.

Comment: What's your question?  Are you getting errors or is the code not doing what you expect/want?

Comment: @SurrealDreams i'm trying to debug some of the javscript in an html5 player and it wont play closed captions because it refuses to find the file

Comment: @JacobMattison so what is the correct split?  basically it's unable to find my closed caption file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript `.split()` method allows you to split a string into an array by providing a keyword (or character), or regex that you want to split up the string on.

e.g. in your case it is splitting on the character "/".

Once it has done the split, you can directly access the items in the array by their index... so the `[2]` gets the 3rd item in the array (since arrays are zero-indexed)

Lets say you want to get the number chunks in this serial number into an array:

```
var sn = '123-456-789';
var chunks = sn.split('-');
//chunks is now an array of: ['123', '456', '789']
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `split` splits up the content into an array. Calling `split("/")` on `"http://192.168.55.108:5555/cc/mypage.html"` will give you:

```
["http:", "", "192.168.55.108:5555", "cc", "mypage.html"]
```

The `[2]` index of that is `"192.168.55.108:5555"`.

What the `if` statement does is check whether they do *not* match:

```
a.split("/")[2] != f.location.href.split("/")[2]
                ^
```

This part of the `if` statement will succeed if `a.split("/")[2]` is not equal to `"192.168.55.108:5555"`.

Calling `split("/")` on `"/cc/subs/TOS-turkish.srt"` will give you:

```
["", "cc", "subs", "TOS-turkish.srt"]
```

Therefore this part of the `if` statement would succeed, as `"subs"` (the `[2]` index of the above array) is not equal to `"192.168.55.108:5555"`.

**However** the `if` statement will fail before that as `a` has no `"://"`, so `a.indexOf("://")` returns `-1` and `0` is not less than or equal to `-1`.

---

To fully break down your `if` statement:

```
   a                         // true: a = "/cc/subs/TOS-turkish.srt"
&& 0 <= a.indexOf("://")     // false: 0 is greater than -1
&& ...[2] != ...[2]          // true: "subs" isn't equal to "192.168.55.108:5555"
```

Due to it returning `false` on `0 <= a.indexOf("://")`, it never gets to the last part anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This comparison tries to see if the domain of the input URL matches the domain of the current page.

`"http://stackoverflow.com".split("/")[2]` gives `stackoverflow.com`.

---

This code might be part of a script that looks at links in a page and does something with them if they point to an offsite resource, like saying: "Hey, you're leaving this website, are you sure you want to continue?".

If you show more code I might be able to give a more conclusive answer.

Answer (score 0):

This evaluates to `false`, since:

```
if (
    a && // <-- if a is true
    0 <= a.indexOf("://") && // <-- if there is '://' in a
    a.split("/")[2] != f.location.href.split("/")[2] // <-- the 2nd part of a, split by '/' (in your case 'subs') is not equal to the 2nd part of f, split by '/' (in your case '192.168.55.108:5555')
) { 
    do_something();
}
```